# How can I do an exact search with MATCH() AGAINST() with a string that has numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MATCH() AGAINST() to search a table, but it ignores all the numbers in AGAINST() and just matches on text.

**My query:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('"1 Cool Person"')
```

**Table:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| id | text                                                                  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1  | I met 1 cool person at mcdonalds.             | this matches :)       |
| 2  | There was a very cool person at burger king.  | this also matches :(  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I get it to only match rows which contain my exact phrase "1 Cool Person"? I don't want it to match "Cool Person" without the number 1.

Comment: Use `LIKE '%1 Cool Person%'` instead?

Comment: It's too slow. My database is 2GB. Is it possible with MATCH() AGAINST()?

Comment: can u try  " 1 Cool Person"